# AttributeError while using shutil.copyfileobj

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I get the below error while using the code :
Code:

```
    with open(temp_file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        shutil.copyfileobj(raw, output_file)
```

Note: raw is a text stream of the type `<class 'bytes'>`

Error:

```
  shutil.copyfileobj(raw, output_file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
  buf = fsrc.read(length)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

How can I write `raw` in to output file?

Comment: A `bytes` object is not any kind of text stream. It's a chunk of bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `bytes` object is not any kind of text stream. It's a chunk of bytes.

`shutil.copyfileobj` is for **copy**ing the contents of one **file**-like **obj**ect to another file-like object. That's why it's called `copyfileobj`. File-like objects are objects that support an interface like the objects returned by `open`, with a concept of a current position, a `write` method for writeable file-like objects, `read` and line-based iteration for readable file-like objects, and often a number of other methods.

A `bytes` object is not a file-like object. It doesn't have any of that. To write bytes to a file, just call the file's `write` method.

```
output_file.write(raw)
```

Comment: What is the difference in reading as a string vs reading as a byte?

Comment: String = text = needs an encoding to be converted to or from a file on-disk. Bytes is just bytes, it's the raw content of the file.